# Non-responding function in one way binding

Tags: html, angular, typescript

The problem may be simple, but I do not see what's wrong right now.

Within the service in my Angular project there is the following function:

```
  public addCompany(){
    let newP:any ={
      "name": "Chay elsarici",
      "password": "1234",
      "email": "chay@touoors.com",
      "coupons": []
      }

     this.myHttpClient.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/couponsystem/admin/insertCompany", newP).subscribe(
       (res)=>{console.log("new company")},
       (err)=>{console.log(err)}
     ); 
  }
```

In the html file of the Componente admin has the following button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="addNewCompany()" value="Click here to insert company "/>
```

And in the file ts of the component admin existing  following function:

```
   public addNewCompany():void{
    console.log("someone click");
    this.myService.addCompany();
    };
```

When I click the button I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addNewCompany is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (admin:13)
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Use the `(click)` directive not the native `onclick` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML you're using

```
onclick="addNewCompany()"
```

You have to use

```
(click)="addNewCompany()"
```

When you use `onclick` you're using the default HTML definition and this will look at the global JavaScript scope. If you use `(click)` the function will run in the scope of your component's controller.

[More info](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding)

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your `Component` doesn't know the `Service` which provides the `addCompany()` method.

Are you importing well your `Service` into the `Component`'s `constructor`?

Are you also declaring it in your `Component`'s `Module` `providers` array?

I guess you may know how to do, but here are the dedicated topics in the Angular documentation:

- [About the DI](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)
- [About the Services architecture](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services)
- [DI Providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers)

As said by @Giovani Vercauteren, Angular as its [own implementation](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events) of `onclick` with the `(click)="..."` binding. So you must change it in your code.

Comment: I made a service import using DI inside the constructor.
And there is a declaration of the admin componente within the app.module
Can also upload this code if you think I have a mistake there.